# how to get and use url with UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I use UIImagePickerController to select an image. i get following keys from info class.

```
UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage    
UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=1000000001&ext=PNG    
UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = public.image
```

i can not use reference url to use this image later. what can i do to use this reference?

```
imageURL = e.Info[new NSString ("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL")].ToString ();

imageBackground = UIImage.FromFile (imageURL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure iOS doesn't allow you direct access to the image file on purpose. Rather it creates a copy of the image (in the form of `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` ). So in order to get a `UIImage` object, you'll be better off using:

```
UIImage image = (UIImage)info.ObjectForKey(new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"));
```

**EDIT**

you could try saving the `UIImage` to your apps documents area then picking it up again. So something along the lines of:

```
UIImage image = (UIImage)info.ObjectForKey(new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"));
NSData imageData = image.AsPNG();
imageData.Cast<Byte>();
byte[] imageBytes = new byte[imageData.Length];
int length = (int)imageData.Length;
Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, imageBytes, 0, length);
string destPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string fileName = "picture.png";
string filePath = Path.Combine(destPath, fileName);
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, imageBytes);
```

I haven't been able to verify this works but it should give you a starting point. You can then access the file later on in the app. Just remember to delete the file once you've finished with it!

Comment: i want to save a reference value and later use it to use this image.

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer. It'll take a copy of the UIImage, save it to a file in the iPhones personal documents folder and you can retreive it whenever you need it.